# ¿Cómo asignar una lista de objetos a una tabla en Sqflite (Flutter)?

Tags: sql, flutter, sqflite

Tengo dos clases, una se trata de un cuestionario, con un nombre, un autor, y una lista de objetos de preguntas, y la otra clase es la clase pregunta. Quiero crear un cuestionario, y asignarle una lista de preguntas a ese cuestionario y quiero guardarlo de forma local para luego enviarlo. ¿Tendría que crear dos tablas y relacionarlas entre sí o cómo se hace?
Un saludo.

Comment: Lo que yo haría es que la primera tabla supongo que es la del usuario y asi mismo supongo que este usuario va a tener un id, deberías crear la tabla de preguntas con un ¨id_user¨ y le pasas el id del usuario, y cuando quieras consultar esas preguntas, las consultas por medio del id_user

Comment: buenos días, para poder resolver tu problema es necesario que publique tu código, los datos que le pide y y posibles imágenes

Comment: @marcosalbertosaavedrasanabr basicamente lo que quiero hacer es poder crear una especie de "encuesta" que pueda guardar de forma local y luego poder enviar, y la clase de esa "encuesta" tiene como atributos un nombre, autor y una lista de preguntas de tipo (en mi caso QuestionData). Este QuestionData tiene una bastantes parámetros, y lo que quiero hacer es en una pestaña poder crear una encuesta, e ir añadiendo tantas preguntas como quiera.

Comment: Buenas, Alejandro, lamentablemente tu pregunta no sigue las normas de la comunidad. Te recomiendo que para obtener mejores respuestas, pongas un poco más de tu parte e inviertas algo de tiempo en entender cómo realizar una buena pregunta en SO. Te ayudará mucho a conseguir respuestas mejores y más rápido, porque facilitas mucho el que te puedan ayudar, si planteas correctamente la pregunta. También, decirte que suele ser imperativo el hecho de poner el código lo que has intentado. https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Basicamente lo que tengo son dos clases, la cual una contiene una lista de objetos de la otra. Una es una clase encuesta, que contiene una lista de objetos pregunta. Quiero saber si tengo que crear dos tablas en la base de datos.

Comment: si no muestra algo de código no le puedo ayuda mucho, puede utiliza esta librería para guarda la información de manera local ***sqlite flutter*** y utiliza una llave primaria tipo alfanumérico "awAswQ4WFe" para identifica el cuestionario

Comment: Buenas podrias crear una tabla de cuestionarios y otra de preguntas de cuestionarios relacionadas o bien tener todo en una. Para guardar una lista en una columna vas a tener que transformar todo en un String con un toJson y volver a recrearla cuando lo necesites con un fromJson. Podes usar drift o sqlLite